# How to subtract 1d array from 2d array's rows in Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, subtraction

What I want to do is to subtract 1d array from other 2d array's rows.
I found, in some case, result was wrong and confused me. Below code worked good as I wanted.

```
lst1 = [[10,11,12,13,14], [20,21,22,23,24], [30,31,32,33,34]]
lstave = [10,20,30,40,50]
# lstave = [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5]  # <- This is also no problem.
# transform them to nparray.
arr1 = np.array(lst1).reshape(3,5)
arrave = np.array(lstave)


for i in range(len(lst1)):
    print(arr1[i] - arrave)
    # print(np.subtract(arr1[i], arrave))   # <- This is also work
```

Then I got following as expected.

```
[  0  -9 -18 -27 -36]
[ 10   1  -8 -17 -26]
[ 20  11   2  -7 -16]
```

However, when I change the array "lstave" to **[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]** and subtract,

```
lst1 = [[10,11,12,13,14], [20,21,22,23,24], [30,31,32,33,34]]
lstave = [1,2,3,4,5]
arr1 = np.array(lst1).reshape(3,5)
arrave = np.array(lstave)

for i in range(len(lst1)):
    print(arr1[i] - arrave)
```

I got following.

```
[9 9 9 9 9]
[19 19 19 19 19]
[29 29 29 29 29]
```

I cannot understand why the only 1st element subtraction performed 5 times.
I feel that broadcast is working wrong way, but I don't know how to fix this.
Can someone help me out?
Thank you,

Comment: I can't notice any different behaviour in your second example. What result did you expect? You don't need to `.reshape(3,5)`.

Comment: Replace lstave with `[1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5]` and it should be clearer to you what's going wrong.  As @MichaelSzczesny points out, this is exactly the right answer.

Comment: You don't need the loop. `arr1 - arrave` does the same (with broadcasting).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does actually work, just:

```
10 - 1
```

Gives:

```
9
```

But:

```
11 - 2
```

Also gives:

```
9
```

---

This is more of a math question.

```
[10 - 1, 11 - 2, 12 - 3, 13 - 4, 14 - 5]
```

Would give:

```
[9, 9, 9, 9, 9]
```

So your code works.

If you make `arrave` to be:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

All the final values would be `10`.